# How count many rows returned in select of Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

can you suggest me how count rows returned in select of Mysql ?

```
$n_quakes = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
             FROM earthquakes 
             WHERE milliseconds >= 1000 
               AND milliseconds <= 2000 
               AND magnitude >= 4 
               AND magnitude <= 8 
               AND ipocentro >= 50 
               AND ipocentro <= 800 
               AND latitude >= 40 
               AND latitude <= 50 
               AND longitude >= 30 
               AND longitude <= 70";
```

In this way i'll know number of rows ?

In my code doesn't work but i don't no if this is error or is in other place of code.

Thanks for help and sorry for my english

Comment: How do you execute this query, and return the results..? Show all the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: _"or is in other place of code"_ - we can't tell, because we don't see any other code.

Comment: sidenote: have a look at the [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) Operator, which will make your query much easier and shorter.

Comment: The number of rows depends upon a number of records in table and condition you have applied.

Comment: Also, you can use `BETWEEN` instead, and cut your conditions in half. `WHERE milliseconds BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000`.

Comment: please prove all relevant codes

Comment: You should have data lying between these criteria otherwise it will return 0

Comment: a `SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM earthquakes` will make getting the value easier. (it's then in `$row['cnt']` if you follow common naming)

Comment: I write an other question with full code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50641555/how-extrapolate-data-by-mysql-and-put-into-array

Answer (score 2):

Try this using between

```
$count = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($coni, "SELECT COUNT(*) as totalCount
             FROM earthquakes 
             WHERE (milliseconds between 1000 and 2000) and (magnitude between 4 and 8) AND (ipocentro between 50 and 800) AND (latitude between 40 and 50) and (longitude between 30 and 70)"));

$actualCount =  $count['totalCount'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, where mysqli_num_rows returns number of rows and $con is database connection variable

```
$n_quakes = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM earthquakes WHERE milliseconds >= 1000 AND milliseconds <= 2000 AND magnitude >= 4 AND magnitude <= 8 AND ipocentro >= 50 AND ipocentro <= 800 AND latitude >= 40 AND latitude <= 50 AND longitude >= 30 AND longitude <= 70"));
```